# Line feeds in comments

Tags: feature-request

I find it a big nuisance that line feeds in writing a comment end the comment and post it. I habitually make many line feeds - then an incomplete comment is posted and I must hurry to fix it in the short time allowed for editing an already submitted comment. I like to have time to think about what I write in my comments. If I make a second or third line feed this is iterated and costs more valuable time.

My suggestion is to treat the line feed like any other character, so that this kind of frequent ''surprises'' ino longer happens.

Comment: or more better, a dedicated submit buttons for comments rather than capturing a `Enter` as submit.

Answer (score 3):

This has already been proposed [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form). The way things are going, it seems unlikely to be implemented any time soon, but you should definitely add your vote to that proposal on MSO.